# REPLACE blank in SQL in import data

Tags: sql, replace

I am importing data into my e-shop. When importing, I lack availability for some products. It thus appears as an empty column in the database.

I need to replace an empty column with `delivery.png` when importing.

I found several patterns on the internet, but none of them work for me, or they return an empty column again.

So far I tried:

```sql
COALESCE(NULLIF([CSV_COL(6)],''), 'delivery.png')
```

or

```sql
REPLACE([CSV_COL(6)], '', 'delivery.png');
```

In the same program I use the same command for another field, where I change vat from 21% to 20% and it works.

```
REPLACE ([CSV_COL(4)], 'VAT 21%', 'VAT 20%')
```

Only if I enter an empty field '' is the result unchanged

Comment: you have two options. 1. open your sql dump and edit the column values using find/replace. 2. (Best) Import the dump into database, then do normal sql update operation.

Comment: Your tries should both work, so my guess is that the field is not empty, maybe it's blank or a non displayable character. You can check it with Len() to see if that is the case

Comment: [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)